# WooCommerce: How to add download button on product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using WooCommerce plugin on our ecommerce website. I want to add a button on the product page that allows users to download a PDF file for free without having to enter to product single page. Also all products needs to have a unique PDF file. Is this possible?

P.S. I have also tried some of the answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible. Use [metaboxio](https://metabox.io/) or [CMB2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/) for creating single product meta field. Where you can upload pdf file for each product when creating or editing product.

Then you can use WooCommerce hook to show there DownLoad button.

Example For MetaBox IO :

Add the above code to the bottom of your functions.php file. Make sure metaboxio plugin is installed and activated. You can go to Plugins - > Add New - > then search with metboxio then install and activate it. After that you can copy paste the code according to advised.

```
    function rox-pdf-button( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'rox-';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'pdf-btn',
        'title' => esc_html__( 'Upload PDF', 'pluginrox' ),
        'post_types' => array('product' ),
        'context' => 'advanced',
        'priority' => 'default',
        'autosave' => 'true',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'id' => $prefix . 'product-pdf',
                'type' => 'file_advanced',
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Upload PDF File', 'pluginrox' ),
                'desc' => esc_html__( 'Here you can upload your pdf file to show on single product page', 'pluginrox' ),
                'mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
                'max_file_uploads' => 5,
                'max_status' => 'true',
                'size' => 5,
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'rox-pdf-button' );
```

In the code I have enabled multiple file upload option , You can make it simple like single file upload option. Check metabox io documentation for that.

Go to your products and now edit any products there you will have option to add PDF now.

For more information how to get the uploaded file url check [this documentation](https://docs.metabox.io/fields/file-advanced/).

Use WooCommerce Single Product hook to publish download button at your product.

Sample Coding To Show Download Button :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'rox_single_download_button', 5 );
    function rox_single_download_button() {
        $files = rwmb_meta( 'rox-product-pdf' );
        foreach ( $files as $file ) {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>"><?php echo $file['name']; ?></a>
        <?php }
    }
```

If you want to add button at product archive page / WooCommerce shop page then you have to apply on product shop or loop hook.

You can try the bellow code , Let me know if it works or not as I did not tested on shop page. I only tested on single page but it should work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'rox_loop_download_button', 5);
function rox_loop_download_button() {
global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
$files = rwmb_meta('rox-product-pdf', '', $product_id);
foreach ($files

as $file) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>"><?php echo $file['name']; ?></a>
<?php }
}
```

For more details [you can check this link.](https://niamrox.com/how-to-add-download-button-on-woocommerce-product-page/)

Comment: Thank you very much the code helped me it showed the upload pdf button but i also need the code for "Single Product hook to publish download button at your product." if you can help me with that also i would really appreciate it .
Thank you once more .

Comment: Please check my answer now , I have edited code , So by that way exactly with the same code you can show download button bellow add-to-cart button at single page.

Comment: It was perfect and is working perfectly but i need the button to be displayed on the product page not on single page

Comment: Please check reply now , I have edited option to add on loop page.

Comment: thank you very very much now it works perfectly you are a life saver